# Sci-fi/fantasy novel where at some point the ship enters a "time warp" where everyone ages rapidly

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember a particular scene from this movie from when I was a kid. A young hero and his girlfriend (princess?) Are in a spaceship going to a planet that is in the middle of a time warp where you need to fly in a specific route to get there or be lost forever. This time warp causes everyone to age rapidly. As the heroes enter the time warp the bad guys catch up and board the ship and there is a sword fight between hero and bad guy and eventually the princess(?) gives birth and the son begins fighting too. The good guys ship then makes it through and the bad guys don't. The hero and girl then look at each other then at her belly like "what the hell?"

That is all I remember, I saw the film when I was about 8 or 9 so it would have been made before 1995 but from what I remember it was probably from the 70's or 80's based on the special effects.

Comment: The title says novel but the body says film what media was it?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/230176/80s-sci-fi-movie-tv-show-where-a-male-character-is-sent-through-a-factory-con (which is newer and has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 7):

This is *[The Ice Pirates](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/TheIcePirates)*.

> The film takes place in a future where water is an immensely valuable substance, both as a commodity and as a currency. Princess Karina (Crosby) is a spoiled princess who purchases captured space pirates Jason (Urich) and Roscoe (Roberts). They then proceed to locate a "lost" planet that contains massive amounts of water. The planet must be approached on a specific course or the ship will be suspended in time forever. The course apparently contains some sort of time distortion.

....

> Karina gives birth and raises her kid while in the time-warping zone, allowing the son to join the fight as a young man and save the rapidly-aging heroes.

**Trailer**

**Time Warp fight**

Found with search terms of *film spaceship "time warp" rapidly age "gives birth"*

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: While it has a few funny scenes, this is a bad, bad film.